# TextToSpeech setLanguage not working?

Tags: java, android, locale, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I am setting my TextToSpeech to use a particular language (English - UK), using the locale "en_GB". But it always uses my devices default language. Is there no way to set it programmatically? I have downloaded the files required for the language and when I change my TTS's default language to 'English - UK' it works but when the default is different the programmatic approach does not work. I have scoured the web to my best but am unable to resolve this issue.

```
    String ttsEngine = "com.google.android.tts";
    txt2Speech = new TextToSpeech(this, this, ttsEngine);
    //Locale ttsLocale = new Locale("eng", "GBR");
    txt2Speech.setLanguage(new Locale("en_GB"));
```

Tried several methods, but none are working. 
Can I not set my TTS's language programmatically?

Thank You

**EDIT: In response to 'A Honey Bustard'**

*Other Code:*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener
```

My `onInit()`

```
public void onInit(int status) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Also I'm calling `.setLanguage()` in my `onCreate()`, as soon as my `TextToSpeech` is initialized. Is that correct? Also I'm only calling it once. It is not required to call it every time right? Also I'm testing on a GS7

Comment: You need to set it in `onInit()` and check the result. That is assuming the `onInit()` status is `SUCCESS`

Comment: @brandall Thank you so much! Putting it in `onInit()` solved the problem. Please post it as an answer so I can mark it as right. :)

Comment: Done. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the language once the Text to Speech Engine has initialised correctly.

```
public void onInit(int status) {

    switch (status) {

        case SUCCESS:
        // Set the language here
        break;
        case ERROR:
         // Something went wrong. You can't set the language
        break;
    }
}
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 3):

Try the second Constructor from [Locale](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#Locale(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) that takes two Strings like this :

```
    txt2Speech.setLanguage(new Locale("en", "GB"));
```

EDIT :

Yes it is usually ok to do instantiate it in onCreate, and it usually only needs and should be done once.

All I can do is show you my working code, I am setting the default language after instantiating in onCreate() :

```
    textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), this);

    textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
```

In my app there are buttons in which you can change the language, which trigger this code (case British English) :

```
  textToSpeech.setLanguage(new Locale("en", "GB"));
```

Maybe it is not available somehow , there are some checks you can validate if the language and country is available. You might find your error there.

```
 if (textToSpeech.isLanguageAvailable(new Locale("en", "GB")) == TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE
   && textToSpeech.isLanguageAvailable(new Locale("en", "GB")) == TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)
```

should return true.

Comment: @A Honey Bustard Thanks for the answer. But still not working. Have also tried `"eng", "GBR"`. Dosen't work. Even tried another language like Spanish but still not working. Any Other Method? Thanks

Comment: Maybe also try the other TTS Constructor that is using the default Engine : text2Speech = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), this);

Comment: @A Honey Bustard No, it still uses the default language. :(

Comment: maybe it is something else in your code, or it is device specific, because I tested it and it works. If theres more code where you use texttospeech post it

Comment: @A Honey Bustard I have edited it and posted some relevant code. Let me know if there is an error in that. Thanks

Comment: @A Honey Bustard Thank you for your efforts +1. However the issue was that I had to `.setLanguage()` in the `onInit()` method. That solved it. (@brandall 's comment on my answer). Thank you for helping me anyways. :)